# Best practice: transmit data set unique ID in (PHP) Web App for processing on the server

Tags: php, web-applications

for quite some time I've been wondering about which is the best practice for transmitting a (unique) reference ID of a data set such that it can be processed (like write back to the database).

I feel a little uneasy writing IDs into html tags since any user who knows how to view how to view the source code gets an essential bit of information.

Example 1: `<input type="button" onclick="updateDataSet(7);" />`

Example 2:

```
<form action="postForm.php" method="post">
    <some form tags here ... />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="7" />
</form>
```

Keeping IDs in a session variable doesn't seem to be an ideal solution either.

Example3 : `$_SESSION["id_data_set"] = 7;`

The least appealing because most obvious way to transmit an ID would be via URL parameter

Example 4: `postForm.php?id=7`

Would appreciate any helpful answers, links etc.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you can use hidden input fields too.. also your first and 4th approach is not too bad at all

Comment: I've seen the practice of hidden fields as @Ashish already mentioned quite often in different software projects.

Comment: Wow, pretty quick :-) thanks
When looking at source codes like right here in stackoverflow or gmail I can't see any IDs, at least not in plain text.
Are the IDs linked to whatever element initiates the post somewhere in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The question is: what can a user *do* knowing or perhaps altering the id?

...

Hopefully nothing. Just *knowing* the id shouldn't give the user anything to work with. So the id is `7`. So what? Big deal.

Of course, the user could *change* the id, submitting data back to the server with the id `8`! Woooooo~
Well, your server is doing sanity checks on any data it receives, isn't it? If the user is allowed to alter data for data set `8`, he could do so one way or another. If he isn't, your server will disregard the received data, right? Right?!

So there's nothing really to worry about, that id in itself is meaningless and can be exposed as much as you want. If this actually poses a problem, your vulnerability lies elsewhere, namely in missing sanity checks on received data.